# Flutter - Build Failed, A problem occurred evaluating project

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run this app then it show me that :- A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
but I add all the plugin according the tutorial which I am following.

Here is the code:- (app\buil.gradle)

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.earthquake_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The problem which is showing my IDE:- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2enAe.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found my own Question Answer...!!!
At first, I did change the project-level build.gradle (dependency sequence and google service version '4.3.5' to '4.3.3'):-

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
```

Then did the second change to the app-level build.gradle (defaultConfig):-

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.earthquake_app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    //This 2 line here...
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Then change on main.dart(As bellow):-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'board_firestore/board_app.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  // these 2 lines
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: BoardApp(),
  ));
}
```

Then I change the app body( in `return Scaffold()`):-

```
body: StreamBuilder(
    //future: FirebaseFirestore.initializeApp(),
    stream: firestoreDb,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length, //documents will be docs
        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
          return Text(snapshot.data.docs[index]['title']);  //documents will be docs
        },
      );
    },
  ),
```

Then in terminal `flutter clean` and then `flutter run`.

I searched a lot and found a lot of solutions but many of them gave many different solutions though everyone has the same problem.